# Что нужно прописать в реестре, чтобы приложение появилось в списке установки и удаления программ?

Tags: windows, реестр

Пишу программный пакет на C++, надо сделать в списке установки и удаления программ ссылку на деинсталлятор. Понятия не имею какой нужен минимальный набор параметров в ключе реестра и куда именно эти параметры писать - в HKEY_CURRENT_USER или в HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE - ведь и там и там есть uninstall. Что ни писал по аналогии с другими установленными программами - свою в списке так и не нашёл.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А что-нить готовое типа `inno setup` использовать?

Comment: Нет - там тонкие настройки входящих в пакет приложений, индивидуальные для каждого пользователя, которые можно сделать только из кода, сторонние продукты не подходят.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. Если вдруг кому будет интересно как добавить своё приложение в список установки и удаления программ - имя программы можно писать в HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\, чтобы не было проблем с админскими правами при записи в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, а в качестве параметров достаточно указать всего два - DisplayName и UninstallString.
Странно что ни один поисковый запрос мне не выдал такую информацию